# How to temporarily disable sitecore indexing while editing items

Tags: solr, lucene, sitecore, data-migration

I am developing a Sitecore project that has several data import jobs running on daily basis. Every time a job is executed, it may update a large amount of Sitecore items (thousands) and I've noticed that all these editings trigger Solr  index updates.

My concern is, I don't really sure if this is better or update everything at the end of the job is. So, I would love to try both options. Could anyone tell me how can I use code to temporarily disable Lucene/Solr indexing and enable it later when I finish editing all items?

Comment: I had a similar issue with an import and if the number of edits goes over 100000 the whole search index gets rebuilt, so you may want to temporarily disable this setting: CheckForThreshold>true</CheckForThreshold>. Otherwise the whole solution may grind to a halt as the the index is being rebuilt while items are still being imported.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common requirement, and you're right to have such concerns. In general it's considered good practice to disable indexing during big import jobs, then rebuild afterwards.

Assuming you're using Sitecore 7 or above, this is pretty much what you need:

```csharp
IndexCustodian.PauseIndexing();
IndexCustodian.ResumeIndexing();
```

Here's a comprehensive article discussing this:

http://blog.krusen.dk/disable-indexing-temporarily-in-sitecore-7/

Comment: I am using `IndexCustodian.PauseIndexing()` but still receiving these logs repeatedly during job execution:  `ManagedPoolThread #6 17:37:45 INFO  Starting update of index for the database 'master' (4 pending).  
ManagedPoolThread #6 17:37:46 INFO  Update of index for the database 'master' done.`  I'm still investigating this with other options. It's painful that they don't have a comprehensive document (or I haven't found out) for this topic.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Martin answer, you can pass (silent=true) when you finish the editing of the item, Something like:

```cs
item.Editing.BeginEdit();
//Change fields values
item.Editing.EndEdit(true,true);
```

The second parameter in **EndEdit()** method force a silent update of the item, which means no Events/Indexing will be triggered on item save.

I feel this is safer than pausing indexing on the whole application level during import process, you just skip indexing of the items you are updating.

**EDIT**:

In case you need to rebuild the index for the updated items after the import process is done, you can use the following code, It will index the content tree starting from RootItemInTree and below:

```cs
var index = Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("Your_Index_Name")
index.Refresh(new SitecoreIndexableItem(RootItemInTree));
```

Comment: That might ignore the change of those items, but how can I ensure that they will be reindexed later after the migration? In my scenario the number of changed items during migration is huge, but total database is gigantic; thus, rebuilding the whole index later may even take much more time.

Comment: @HarryNinh I have updated the answer with code sample to refresh items index

Answer (score 3):

To disable indexing during large import/update tasks you should wrap your logic inside a `BulkUpdateContext` block. You can also use other wrappers like the `EventDisabler` to stop events from being fired if that is appropriate in your context. Alternatively you could wrap your code in an `EditContext` and set it to silent. So your code could end up something like this:

```cs
using (new BulkUpdateContext())
using (new EditContext(targetItem, false, true))
{
    // insert update logic here...
}
```

here is a older question that discusses this topic: [Optimisation tips when migrating data into Sitecore CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5385750/202)